# Error acquiring form elements by ID

Tags: google-apps-script

this is actually my first post here, I've found a lot of answers on this site but never asked a question so here it goes!
I'm lost as to why I can't seem to get this to work. I've checked, checked and triple checked to make sure that my form ID's and element ID's are correct but still I get nothing.
Here is the chunk of code that I'm working with:

```
function UpdateForm()
{

// Acquire Organization form by ID
var Oform = FormApp.openById("XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX");
//Acquire specific form elements by element ID
  var ServiceList = Oform.getItemById(1234496377).asCheckboxItem();
  var NeedsList = Oform.getItemById(694738992).asCheckboxItem();
  var ServiceAgeList = Oform.getItemById(1874307280).asCheckboxItem();
  var NeedsAgeList = Oform.getItemById(476187889).asCheckboxItem();
  var CountyList = Oform.getItemById(265793198).asListItem();

// Acquire Volunteer form by ID
var Vform = FormApp.openById("XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX");
//Acquire specific form elements by element ID
  var VCountyList = Vform.getItemById(1434441318).asListItem();
  var InterestList = Vform.getItemById(277694527).asCheckboxItem();
```

The first section for the organization form works fine, but the second section for the volunteer section does not. I get error:

> TypeError: Cannot call method "asListItem" of null. (line 16, file
>   "UpdateForm")

I've tried switching the VCountyList and InterestList with the same error (except of course then it's a null asCheckboxItem)

I've tried commenting out the entire first chunk for the Organization form because I wasn't sure if the script could handle more than one form but I get the same error.

I've tried just running the Vform chunk from the script editor in the form itself (all of this code is running from the script editor in the submission sheet) and that didn't work either; same error.

I'm totally lost.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know this answer may seem elementary, but I would do `Vform.getItems()` and verify that the item you're looking for is actually the item you want.  Maybe even something as tedious as this:

```
var Vform = FormApp.openById("xxxxxxxxxx");
var items = Vform.getItems();
for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++)
  Logger.log(items[i].getId() + ': ' + items[i].getType());
```

Sorry if this is not the answer you were looking for.  I thought maybe this kind of debugging would help.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it out, anything helps!

Comment: Ima real dummy head...somehow after checking it so many times I still had one of the ID's wrong! But what's weird is that it would still stop on the other ID saying it was null when I put it first even though it was correct...strange. Thank you so much!!!!